# setInterval; Number of milliseconds for beats in song, equation

Tags: javascript, html, math

I've got a pretty tough problem spinning in my head, and I'll slap myself when somebody points out what I'm doing wrong, but here is the deal. I have a simple javascript counter that by default counts up by one each second. Because setInterval is at 100 milliseconds. I am playing an audio file and I wan't the counter to show how many beats the song has. My limited knowledge of math and javascript have left me to ask the public. The song is very fast. It is 27 seconds long, and has 224 beats in it. What should setInterval be set to in order to count each beat? Sorry if this is irrelevant, but I think it's pretty javascript related. Thank You So Much, I really need help with this. :)

Comment: `27` seconds for `224` beats has `224 / 27` beats per second in it...

Comment: This is pretty much entirely a math question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't worry. It would be nice to see your setInterval code to make this more of a StackOverflow question.

So, you know the number of beats in the song. I assume that it is the total number of beats in the 27 second song and not the BPM (beats per minute). If you have BPM, this would be different.

Set the setInterval to the total length of the song divided by the total number of beats in the song.

```
27/224
```

Lastly you need that number in milliseconds to feed it into setInterval. So multiply it by 1000.

```
setInterval(function(){ console.log("beat"); }, 1000*(27/224));
```

Answer (score -1):

I have just figured it out. (nobody else will ever have this problem.) But it's 27/224 = 0.12 so 120 milliseconds if you convert it. And playing my song, while running the code brings it up to 224 so Yay!